# Trigonometry in C

Tags: c, trigonometry

I'm a beginner in C and have this problem: I'm supposed to make an app where you insert the coordinates of a triangle's vertices, and then it prints details about its area, perimeter and most interesting of all, it's supposed to print its angles. The code is supposed to be written using the double tangent equation from Heron's formula. I've tried doing it using `atan()`, but I guess I should add `+n` to avoid going out of the domain. Don't know how though.
[Here's the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0boP.png). And below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI  (4. * atan(1))

int main() {
    // Defining floats
    
    float xa, ya, xb, yb, xc, yc, s, P, a, b, c, x, y, z, alphadeg, alpharad, betadeg, betarad, gammadeg, gammarad;

    // Inserting coordinates of each points

    printf("Insert the first point's coordinates (a space should be between the X and Y coordinate):\n"); 
    scanf("%f %f", &xa, &ya);
    
    printf("Insert the second point's coordinates (a space should be between the X and Y coordinate):\n");
    scanf("%f %f", &xb, &yb);
    
    printf("Insert the third point's coordinates (a space should be between the X and Y coordinate):\n");
    scanf("%f %f", &xc, &yc);
    
    // Calculating and printing length of each side

    printf("Distance between point 1 and 2: %f\n", sqrt(pow(xa - xb, 2) + pow(ya - yb, 2)));
    printf("Distance between point 1 and 3: %f\n", sqrt(pow(xa - xc, 2) + pow(ya - yc, 2)));
    printf("Distance between point 2 and 3: %f\n", sqrt(pow(xb - xc, 2) + pow(yb - yc, 2)));
    
    // Defining each side

    a = sqrt(pow(xa - xb, 2) + pow(ya - yb, 2));
    b = sqrt(pow(xa - xc, 2) + pow(ya - yc, 2));
    c = sqrt(pow(xb - xc, 2) + pow(yb - yc, 2));

    // Defining s as the parameter from Heron's formula

    s = ((a + b + c) / 2);

    // Defining P as the area from Heron's formula

    P = sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));

    // Printing the area and perimeter of the triangle

    printf("The area of your triangle is %f\n", P);
    printf("The perimeter of your triangle is %f\n", a + b + c);
 

    // Angles
    
    /*
    tan(alpha/2)=sqrt(((P-b)*(P-c))/(P*(P-a)));
    tan(beta/2)=sqrt(((P-a)*(P-c))/(P*(P-b)));
    tan(gamma/2)=sqrt(((P-a)*(P-a))/(P*(P-c))); 
    
    Let 
    x = tan(alpha/2)
    y = tan(beta/2)
    z = tan(gamma/2)
    */
   
    x = sqrt(((P - b) * (P - c)) / (P * (P - a)));
    y = sqrt(((P - a) * (P - c)) / (P * (P - b)));
    z = sqrt(((P - a) * (P - b)) / (P * (P - c)));
    alphadeg = (atan(x)) * 360 / PI;
    betadeg = (atan(y)) * 360 / PI;
    gammadeg = (atan(z)) * 360 / PI;
    alpharad = 2 * (atan(x));
    betarad = 2 * (atan(y));
    gammarad = 2 * (atan(z));

    printf("The value of the alpha angle is %0.3f\n", alphadeg);
    printf("The value of the beta angle is %0.3f\n", betadeg);
    printf("The value of the gamma angle is %0.3f\n", gammadeg);

    printf("%f = %f", PI, (alpharad + betarad + gammarad));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It only works for the pythagorean triangle, coordinates as following: 0,4 3,0 3,4

Comment: please edit your question and add relevant information there ... and you forgot to ask a question

Comment: Note: to convert from radians to degrees, multiply by 180/PI, not 360

Comment: This question is missing: what is your test case, what are the expected results, what are the actual results.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `+n` or "going out of the domain".  Are you worried about computations like `sqrt(((P-b)*(P-c))/(P*(P-a)))` where `P*(P-a)` may be zero or very close to zero?  That is what the [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function is for.  So you can do `alpha = atan2(sqrt((P-b)*(P-c)), sqrt(P*(P-a));`.

Comment: Suggest `#define PI 3.14159265358979323846` rather than `4. * atan(1)` to remove the computation (though the compiler should optimize for you). The values are the same for all practical purposes. If using gcc/clang, you can use the predefined `M_PI` for the value of PI after including `math.h` and defining `_GNU_SOURCE`.

Comment: `M_PI` and other constant values are also available in MSVC but you must `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` before `#include <math.h>`

Comment: @TimRandall True, but please note that the OP needs to double that angle.

Comment: @TimRandall If you look at the formula I have linked, there is the tangent of alpha/half, which means i need to multiply the radian by 2*180/PI, so I just made it shorter -> 360/PI

Comment: It was supposed to calculate the angles of any triangle given correctly, @Bob__ found the solution already so I declare this case closed. Thanks everyone for your help! I'm just starting programming so it really means much to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by a misunderstanding of the mathematical formulas.

```C
// That's the formula to calculate the semi perimeter of a triangle
// given the length of its sides a, b and c.
s = ((a + b + c) / 2);

// Defining P as the area from Heron's formula
P = sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
```

The name `P`, here, is misleading (`s` too, actually) and not only because they are one-letter variable names. In the following formulas, the OP uses `P` instead of the semi-perimeter:

```C
x = sqrt(((P - b) * (P - c)) / (P * (P - a)));
//         ^         ^          ^    ^           You should use 's' instead.
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!! This solves it. How stupid of me that I didn't check the units. I appreciate your help :D

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to add epsilon like below:

```
float EPSILON = 0.1
x = sqrt(((P-b)*(P-c))/(EPSILON+P*(P-a)));
```

Comment: Why? Adding any random x to the denominator only means that failure occurs at -x on the number line instead of at zero.

Comment: The code was correct, it was a mathematical error in the formula that I have linked in the description - there should be s except of P in it. Thanks for help though! I appreciate :D